# New Rear Wheel goes out of true

Tags: wheel-truing

Couple of months back, I installed a new rear wheel for my road bike. Its a wieman LP18.

Since then I had to get it trued at-least three times. Is this normal for new wheel?

Comment: How many miles have you put on it in the past couple of months?

Comment: I would say less than 500 miles.

Comment: "Normal" is a place in Ohio.  When I've built wheels it's taken a few hundred miles for them to "break in" and maintain true.  I bought a wheel from Peter White, however, and he guaranteed it to be true for life (and so far it's been great).  A factory-built wheel should be somewhere in-between.

Comment: lol. I didnt know that you had to break in wheels.

Answer (score 4):

It's normal for a new wheel that was under-tensioned, unevenly tensioned, inadequately stress-relieved or whose spokes are twisted.

Either that or it's being abused - ie. if you're really throwing it around, or are carrying heavy loads on the 24-hole version.

The repeated re-truing may end up with a decent wheel, since you're just performing the stress-relieving step while riding instead of in the workshop. It may equally damage the wheel before you get there, and you really shouldn't have to pay to fix a bad build.

Answer (score -2):

after it out of true again,put some locktite inside every nipples,but if you are constantly doing aggressive riding,you have to consider other solution.